# ObjC IOS: Убрать затемнение при вызове presentPopupViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Доброго времени. Пишу приложение для IOS. Для вывода одного UIViewController в другом использую метод presentPopupViewController. Проблема в том, что вся остальная часть вокруг нового контроллера очень сильно затемняется (на симуляторе черный цвет). Как избавиться от этого затемнения?
Код вызова:

```
MyDropDown* mdd = [[MyDropDown alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyDropDown" bundle:nil];
    [self presentPopupViewController:mdd animationType:MJPopupViewAnimationSlideTopTop];
```

Comment: можно было хотя бы написать что этот ваш presentPopupViewController это метод из библиотеки с гитхаба?

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему так:

```
id bcg = self.mj_popupBackgroundView;
UIView *bcgView = bcg;
bcgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо взять с гитхаба тот самый [MJPopupViewController](https://github.com/martinjuhasz/MJPopupViewController) который вы используете для своего попапа, и в файле `UIViewController+MJPopupViewController.m` удалить следующие строки:

```
// customize popupView
popupView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:popupView.bounds].CGPath;
popupView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
popupView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5, 5);
popupView.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
popupView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
popupView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
popupView.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

Comment: Этот код отвечает за тень отбрасываемую контроллером. Править саму библиотеку я бы не особо хотел. Плюс ко всему я недостаточно опытен в ObjC.

Comment: ну тогда сразу после того, как попап создан вручную убирайте все манипуляции с леером - тот же код из ответа, но наоборот.